# Proper way of passing a bunch of parameters to class

Tags: php, oop, class, parameters

I have something like this

```
class Demo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

and need to pass a bunch of parameters (up to 20) to Demo class (name, email, address, etc).

From what I know, there are 2 ways of doing that:

first way - pass an array:

```
$params = array('name' => 'test', 'email' => 'test' ... );
$demo = new Demo($params);
```

then change conctructor to __conctruct($data).

second way - create a setter for each parameter, so we do something like this:

```
$demo = new Demo();
$demo->setName('test');
$demo->setEmail('test@test.com');
```

Which one is better? Second way requires a lot of typing, but I think it follows OOP principles. Is there other way of setting parameters?

Edit: of course we can pass parameters directly $demo = new Demo('test', 'test@test.com'...) but you need to know the order of parameters, which might be a problem.

Comment: Not knowing the details I have to say that if your class needs 20 parameters it has way too much responsibility

Comment: In real world you'll have situations where one class must process a lot of parameters (data from contact forms, or some rss/xml objects)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing your second way you can always chain your setters.

```
class Foo {
public function setA($a) {
    $this->a = $a;
    return $this;
}

public function setB($b) {
    $this->b = $b;
    return $this;
}
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setA('a')->setB('b');
```